# Https page loads in chrome not in android webview if it is not updated/disabled

Tags: android, ssl, webview, https

I am facing a very strange problem. In my application I have couple of pages where an URL is loaded inside an webview. All the urls are https and the certificates are also very much valid.

Some of the users complain that a specific page is not loading. it shows white screen. According to our test the page in question loads in almost all android devices.

After having some sleepless night what I have found is that **this problem happens only for the devices where "Android System Webview" is not updated to the latest version (but it is updated to quite latest version itself like mid 2016)**. And this happens if user turns off Auto update in playstore.

After find the problem when I debug the webview in the devices where Android System Webview is not updated, I found that I am receiving an SSL error (primary error 5 SSL_INVALID).

I know that this problem can be easily bypassed by ignoring SSL errors. But I don't want to bypass the SSL error as there is no problem in my SSL certificate.

I have tried to load some different SSL urls on the above said devices. And I found that some websites are not working also. I have compared the SSL certificates also. There is no major difference there.

One example of the site which is not loading is https://www.nets.eu/no-nb/Pages/default.aspx

Do anybody know what has recently updated on Android System Webview which cause the problem?

Is there anyway this issue can be solved other than ignoring SSL errors?